# Copy home template to make changes & test on hidden menu

Tags: joomla

I want to copy my Homepage (index page) and make the copy appear on the hidden part of my website as so i can make changes and test it before i put the new page up live...

So i basically want to be able to type a URL and see the page on the web, yet I don't want that page to apart of the websites main menu...

Comment: do you want a copy of the whole site to make drastic changes, or you just want to be able to edit a single page/menu?

Comment: Well i have figured out how to send articles to a different page, yet i want to copy the whole home page, including Flash banners etc. to a new URL to make fairly drastic changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new menu from the menu management name it like 'hidden menu' or something else then add new menu item on it .
Don't publish your hidden menu elsewhere in site. Assign your copied template to your new menu item created under hidden menu.
Now you can copy the link of new menu to the url.

Comment: I can move articles in the way that u have mentioned above, but to place a whole template there, so i can test and edit is where im having the issues... I preview the template (copy) and it is identical to the original home page.. yet when i got the URl "index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage" it wont show the flash banner or the simpeEmailForm that has been added... Any ideas...??

Comment: Where the flash banner and email form is shown from? module, component or from template.

Comment: I'm sorry i dont understand what your asking...?
when i set the the copied template to appear on the 'hiddenItemsMenu'  and then type the URL provided only 1 article appears.. But not the flash banner or any other modules.. eg. 'simpleEmailForm' &/or 'newsFlash'...??

Comment: Yet when i view the template in the template manager all the modules, articles & banner(s) are there in plain view... but not on the URL that is provided in the 

'Menu' >> 'hiddenMenuItems' ...?

Comment: add "&Itemid=1" to the url provided by hidden menu item and 1 is the id(ItemId) of that menu which you can get from the menu item manager. If the problem still persist, recheck all the modules on module manager if it's published to all the menu item.

Comment: You need to assign your modules to the new menu links.

Answer (score 0):

Copy (aka duplicate) your content article (= index page, hompage content). You can access it via URI `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=<ID>` and replace `<ID>` with your articles ID.

Comment: Please read the the response i have posted to user "Prakash". Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

This is for Joomla 3:

- Go into the Template Manager and copy your existing template to make a new one e.g. 'YourTemplateName2'.
- Note that a style 'YourTemplateName2 - Default' will automatically be created as well.
- Edit the new template.
- Preview the new template, either:

  - In Styles, using the 'eye' icon to the left of the style name, or
  - In Templates, using the link 'Preview' under the style name, or
  - Using the URL GET parameter 'template' like this: 
    "http://www.example.com//index.php?template=YourTemplateName2

If you use the 'Preview' link or the 'eye' icon, you'll get a preview with the extra parameter 'tp=1' - this shows you some extra info, but if you want to preview the site exactly as it'll look to the user then you can just delete this parameter.

When you're happy with your changes, either set the new template to be the default template, or copy the details from your new template to the existing one.

Hope that helps.